# select distinct values using spring data rest

Tags: java-8, spring-data-rest

I'm using java 8 and spring-data-rest to create API on my data.

I have a table Car(id, name, date...)

I'm trying to have an endpoint to retrieve distinct car names.

here's my Repository :

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "cars")    
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Long> {
    //What i want to do
    //@Query(value = "select distinct c.name as name from Car c")
    @Query(value = "select distinct c from Car c")
    List<Car> findDistinctName();      
}
```

The query commented does not work , i have an exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PersistentEntity must not be null!
```

apparently this is the normal behavior of SDR.

I tried another solution by using `Projections`

```
@Projection(name = "name", types = {Car.class})
public interface CarName {
    String getName();
}
```

but i cant get the distinct values, any idea?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an (ugly) workaround, using jpql :

`@Query(value = "select c from Car C WHERE c.id IN (SELECT min(ca.id) FROM Car ca Group by ca.name)")`

Answer (score 1):

All you need, to do if you need a distinct list of cars, is such this query method:

```
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Long> {
    List<Car> findDistinctBy();
}
```

Spring Data JPA supports the [Distinct](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation) keyword in repository query methods to set a distinct flag on the query to be created.

Comment: in fact, i need distinct car names, i tried the solution and i'm still getting the same result

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove the @Query annotation.
Just
`List<Car> findDistinctName();`  or `List<Car> findNameDistinct();` should suffice.
It will automatically generate the query `select c.name from Car c`